# Parsing a .json column in Power BI

Tags: json, parsing, powerbi

I want to parse a .json column through Power BI. I have imported the data directly from the server and have a .json column in the data along with other columns. Is there a way to parse this json column?

Example:

```
       Key      IDNumber    Module      JsonResult  
       012      200         Dine        {"CategoryType":"dining","City":"mumbai"',"Location":"all"} 
       97       303         Fly         {"JourneyType":"Return","Origin":"Mumbai (BOM)","Destination":"Chennai (MAA)","DepartureDate":"20-Oct-2016","ReturnDate":"21-Oct-2016","FlyAdult":"1","FlyChildren":"0","FlyInfant":"0","PromoCode":""} 
       276      6303        Stay        {"Destination":"Clarion Chennai","CheckInDate":"14-Oct-2016","CheckOutDate":"15-Oct-2016","Rooms":"1","NoOfPax":"2","NoOfAdult":"2","NoOfChildren":"0"}
```

I wish to retain the other columns and also get the simplified parsed columns.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Use Json.Document function like this

```
let
    ...
    your_table=imported_the_data_directly_from_the_server,
    json=Table.AddColumn(your_table, "NewColName", each Json.Document([JsonResult]))
in
    json
```

And then expand record to table using `Table.ExpandRecordColumn`

Or by clicking this button

[image]

Comment: I followed these steps and got new column contains "Record" as a value in it successfully, but not able to expand the column as it contains null values also. If I apply a filter to remove null value rows then it allow me to expand. How to expand with null values? as other column values are needed where expanded values will be null.

Comment: @Priyanka Mane, 
I don't understand your problem. Nulls are successfully expanded to record, containing null values in fieldnames

`let
    t = #table({"col"}, {{[q=1, w=2, e=3]},{null},{[w=22, e=33, r=4]}}),
    expand = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(t, "col", {"q","w","e","r"}, {"q","w","e","r"})
in
    expand`

Answer (score 58):

There is an easier way to do it, in the Query Editor on the column you want to read as a json:

- Right click on the column
- Select Transform>JSON

then the column becomes a Record that you can split in every property of the json using the button on the top right corner.

[image: split columns]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! I spent a good hour looking at coding solutions, until I saw this, which did it with a few clicks. Thank you!

Comment: THIS! I've read so many answers jumping through hoops when there's a built in function that exists in Power BI!

Comment: Thanks! The above answer really helped.

Comment: EXACTLY what I need! Thanks bud!

Comment: what about the scenario in which the json is deeply layered? I'm not sure anyone addressed overly nested JSONs

Answer (score 1):

Use **`Json.Document()`** function to convert string to Json data.

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://localhost:18091/pools/default/buckets/Aggregation/docs/AvgSumAssuredByProduct"))[json]),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each not Text.Contains([Name], "type_")),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Name", "AvgSumAssuredByProduct"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Value", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Answer (score -7):

```
import json
from urllib import urlopen
import string
from UserList import *
l=[]
j=[]
d_base=urlopen('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/193888/fields/1.json?results=1')
data = json.load(d_base)
for k in data['feeds']:
        name = k['entry_id']
        value = k['field1']
        l.append(name)
        j.append(value)

print l[0]
print j[0]
```

**this python code may useful for you **
**270
  1035
**

Comment: How can you use Python in Power BI?

Comment: hello from the future https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-august-2018-feature-summary/#python